# iPhone Jquery run function on confirm = true

Tags: jquery, iphone

I'm using html / jquery to make my phone list, and I want to have a confirm dialog to do the action, but even if I tap cancel, the action is fired...

also, is there any chance of using jquery and cycript together?

Thanks

```
$(".btns_numeros").click(function() {
        confirmacao($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    //
    function confirmacao(numero) {
        var resposta = confirm ("Ligar para "+numero+" ?");
        if (resposta) {
            var ligar = "<a href='tel:"+numero+"'></a>";
            window.location.href = ligar;
        } else {
```

event.preventDefault();

```
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding

```
event.preventDefault();
```

solves the question